# There is no `margin`, `padding`, and `border` in two div, why there is space between them?

Tags: css, vue.js

I use vue.js create a page(`index.vue`), there are `header.vue` and `home.vue`:

index.vue code:

```
<template>
  <div class="index">
    <i-header></i-header>
    <router-view></router-view>
    <i-footer></i-footer>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

  import Home from './首页/home.vue'
  import Header from '../components/header/header.vue'
  import Footer from '../components/footer/footer.vue'


  export default {
    methods: {

    },

    components: {
      'home':Home,
      'i-header': Header,
      'i-footer': Footer
    }
  };
</script>

<style scoped>

  .index {

  }

</style>
```

but there is a space between `header` component and `home` components.

See the `box` model of them:

[First](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jsc3K.jpg)

[Second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OZMf.jpg)

you see, they all have no `margin`, `padding`, and `border`, why there is space between them?

Comment: Does header have `display: block;`? Or `display: inline-block;`.

Comment: Do you mean the `header`'s children elements/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so firstly you should check if you have some normalize in your project, because white-space can come from inline-blocks or added by the browser to specific tags.
 2. you should check inside your header tag child elements because they can have some margins.
 3. also it will be better if you will send some codepan with full structure and style that you have in the browser.

Comment: You are right. I'd like to add several words. There are many reasons why this gap might appear. One of the reasons is the `display: inline-block` of header: https://codepen.io/3rdthemagical/pen/wyLXOG

Comment: Whats the meaning of `normalize` in your way?

Comment: if you use inline-blocks in will be better to make some structure with wrapper like
<div class='wrapper'>
      <div class='child-element'></div>
     <div class='child-element'></div>
</div>
so for wrapper you will add styles
.wrapper {font-size: 0}
.child-element {font-size: 16px //your font size here}

so its helps when you use inline-blocks,its remove white-spaces between them.

also you provide not good codepan,because there i don't see the problem.